# Save valued of Alert Dialog using shared preference

Tags: android

How to save and view user input value of Alert Dialog's edit Text filed.
i already saved the value using shared preference but when Alert Dialog load for second time value is not appeared.

save the values using shared Preference

```
alertDialog1.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "SEND", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      //  alertDialog1.dismiss();
            //formatted url
            String sendURL = agentName.getText().toString();
            String name = nameURl.concat(sendURL).concat(nameUR2);
            agentName.setText(name);
           // setURLNANME(name);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
            EditText nm;
            String NAME = "namekkey";
            String myPreferences = null;

            nm = findViewById(R.id.input_agentname);
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(myPreferences,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            if (sharedPreferences.contains(NAME)){
                nm.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(NAME,""));
            }


        }
    });

    alertDialog1.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alertDialog1.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog1.show();
}
```

once user type name and send want view the value again and again when user view the alert dialog.

Comment: I don't see the code where you save to shared preferences anywhere.  You might want to include that, as that code could be where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Tim will re check

Answer (score 0):

First you need to retrieve the name from the `SharedPreferences`:

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(myPreferences,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String name = sharedPreferences.getString(NAME,"");
```

Then set the text of the `textview` with the value before you display the dialog:

```
nm.setText(name);
```

Comment: Thank you Khalid i will check

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write any code to store data in shared preferences.
you can write that before dismiss method.

```
alertDialog1.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
      editor.putString(Name,nm.getText().toString());
      editor.apply();
      alertDialog1.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you hesam i will check